# .NET Framework issue which I can't fix without formatting the PC

Tags: windows, windows-10, .net-framework

I'm having an issue which I know I can fix by formatting the computer. Though, yesterday I was all afternoon installing it and installing all my programs, and I didn't want to go over it again...

This seems to happen when there's a bad problem and I have to run SFC (cause of that would be modifications in the system to change its aspect). And the error (on Winaero Tweaker) is the following, which only appears after what I described, and never happens if no problem appears on the computer:

```
System.IO.IOException: The parameter is incorrect.

   em Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   em Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKeyInternal(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, Object registrySecurityObj, RegistryOptions registryOptions)
   em Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey)
   em WinaeroTweaker.Classes.TweakerFavorites.PopulateFavorites()
   em WinaeroTweaker.MainForm.PopulateFavoritesToNode(String RootNodeName)
   em WinaeroTweaker.MainForm.AddNodes()
   em WinaeroTweaker.MainForm.MainForm_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

************** Loaded assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Versão da assemblagem: 4.0.0.0
    Versão Win32: 4.8.4341.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
WinaeroTweaker
    Versão da assemblagem: 0.19.1.0
    Versão Win32: 0.19.1.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Winaero%20Tweaker/WinaeroTweaker.exe
----------------------------------------
System
    Versão da assemblagem: 4.0.0.0
    Versão Win32: 4.8.4300.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Versão da assemblagem: 4.0.0.0
    Versão Win32: 4.8.4341.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Versão da assemblagem: 4.0.0.0
    Versão Win32: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
WinaeroControls
    Versão da assemblagem: 2.0.2.7
    Versão Win32: 2.0.2.7
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Winaero%20Tweaker/WinaeroControls.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Versão da assemblagem: 4.0.0.0
    Versão Win32: 4.8.4190.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Versão da assemblagem: 4.0.0.0
    Versão Win32: 4.8.4341.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Versão da assemblagem: 4.0.0.0
    Versão Win32: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms.resources
    Versão da assemblagem: 4.0.0.0
    Versão Win32: 4.7.3190.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_pt_b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Versão da assemblagem: 4.0.0.0
    Versão Win32: 4.8.4270.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Versão da assemblagem: 4.0.0.0
    Versão Win32: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
mscorlib.resources
    Versão da assemblagem: 4.0.0.0
    Versão Win32: 4.7.3190.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/mscorlib.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_pt_b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
```

Note: this is in Portuguese. If more translation is necessary please tell me and I'll translate any words (though, I think the main parts are translated).

Would anyone know if this is a system problem or a problem of the program itself? If it from the system, how can I fix it? (If it's from the program, I'll have to ask the developer and see if he can fix it - or just format this thing again...)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: "and I didn't want to go over it again..." This is why a make disk images of my drive every month.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.  Saying you have a problem isn’t helpful, I can’t tell if the .NET exception is the problem, or you have some other problem.  The File IO exception is with the registry key load function more than likely, but that’s a complete guess in the dark, since you have specified really no specifics

Comment: Is the problem that when you launch WinaeroTweaker it crashes?

Comment: @Ramhound The thing is I've no idea what the problem is. I only know it would appear when I tried to open Winaero Tweaker. I could "Quit" or "Continue". If I continued, it wouldn't work decently. But I don't know if it was a system problem or a Winaero Tweaker programming problem. That's why the question is somewhat vague. I appologize for that. Also worth mentioning I had to format the computer once again, so the error is gone (tomorrow is my last day on vacations and I'm losing today with this... Sad). But if you know a reason, coukd be useful in case this appears again (honestly hope not).

Comment: It’s going to take more than a day to diagnose the problem and that’s only if you are able to provide the information necessary to do so.  If you format the machine, any chance to diagnose the problem, will be lost making your question unanswerable

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can fix by formatting the computer. ....   ... And the error
> (on Winaero Tweaker)

Possibly reinstalling Windows may be the way.

Consider a Repair Install. Uninstall Winaero Tweaker first.  Note the 3 methods and try the first after uninstalling Winaero Tweaker and other third party apps that are not mainstream. See if the normal repair fixes things. Nothing lost.  The third option may be necessary in the event of (a) very severe damage or (b) User Profile damage.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.
If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key,
then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to proceed, according to the severity of the error.

> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.

Comment: That’s entirely your choice, if I were you, I would get the reason your unable to perform a Windows Reset diagnosed

Comment: If the Keep Everything did not work (usually does 75% of the time), it may be a Profile issue and so you should back up and try the 3rd option (Keep Nothing). That will work as it is essentially a new install.

Comment: I was in a hurry to have the computer ready for work today. Had been getting it ready and then that happens, so I couldn't really be trying various things. As soon as I saw more problems coming, I just formated it and installed from 0. I'd need to be on vacations for testing. I appologize. I'd delete the question, but seems I can't. I'll have to think more before asking. Though, I thought it would be a quick answer. Damn.